# False-positive Sonar issue

Tags: java, sonarqube, nullable

Question: why does sonar give me warning ("Change this issue so that it does not always evaluate to "false."). I've been able to prove that `if (info == null)` evaluates to `true` when the `requestEntity` doesn't contain a payload that's found in the db. So how can I get rid of this false positive?  Does it have something to do with the `@Nullable`, `@Checkfornull`, or `@Nonnull` annotations?  I know the postForObject method uses the `@Nullable` annotation.

```
      Info info = restTemplate.postForObject(connectionString, requestEntity,
         Info.class);

      if (info == null) {
         throw new ApplicationException(Constants.NO_RESULT_ERROR_CODE);
      }
```

Here is the `postForObject` method:

```
    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> T postForObject(URI url, @Nullable Object request, Class<T> responseType)
            throws RestClientException {

        RequestCallback requestCallback = httpEntityCallback(request, responseType);
        HttpMessageConverterExtractor<T> responseExtractor =
                new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<>(responseType, getMessageConverters());
        return execute(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
    }
```

Comment: Is this the only code? Particularly, is there any code between the `postForObject()` call and the test for null? If so, please show it.

Comment: No it's immediately after, as shown.  I think there's some issue with sonar not recognizing that postForObject is capable of returning null but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: can you post "postForObject"?

Comment: Probably `postForObject(...)` never returns a null therefore `info == null` is always false

Comment: @JaphethOngeri-inkalimeva i've confirmed that it can return null.

Comment: @RoyShahaf I updated the question with the postForObject method

Comment: Perhaps you'll let us judge that it really never returns null by posting all the relevant code...

Comment: @RoyShahaf I said it CAN return null if the db doesn't contain what's in the request payload, which means the condition does NOT always return false.  I sent a request to simulate this and it is indeed the case.  This is the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `// NOSONAR` on the reported line (and probably explain why you ignored this issue).

That's not the best solution but it works (at least, when used in Eclipse).

You can also use `@SuppressWarnings` with the issue type (eg: like `squid:02020`).